# Database indexes cakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two tables, namely 'Customer' and 'Event'. The relations between these two are as follows:

Event

```
var $belongsTo = array(
         ...
    'Customer'=>array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
    )
    );
```

Customer

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

Each and every customer record holds a company id as well as currently logged in user. What I would like to achieve is to get all of the events for a day, related only to a particular company, but that is of course not working since the event table does not hold company id. Maybe the following find call will help to understand the issue better:

```
$conditions = array('company_id'=>CakeSession::read("Auth.User.company_id"), 'date'=>date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow));
$tomorrowsEvents = $this->find('all', array(
                                'conditions'=>$conditions, 'contain'=>array('User', 'Customer')));
```

Moreover, a customer belongs to a company and a company has many customers, just as follows:

Customer

```
var $belongsTo = array(
        'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
);
```

Company

```
    var $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ),
    'Customer'=>array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In your question, please describe  how the Company model relates to Event and Customer. Is it Customer BelongsTo Company and Company HasMany Customer?

Comment: I have just updated it.

Comment: @Domas Did you noticed something? Company and Event are related to gather by HABTM relation through Customer!

Comment: There is no relation between events and company. That is what the question is all about. Events belong to customer that belongs to company. And what I want to do is to list events that are related to a particular company.

Comment: @Domas You just said it! `list events that are related to a particular company.` so it should have a relation.

Comment: Events are related to user by User_id and user table holds company_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually do this query "backwards" by doing it from Customer, and using the containable behavior to contain the related Events:

```
$this->Customer->find('all', 
     array(
       'conditions' => array(
           'company_id' => CakeSession::read("Auth.User.company_id")
        ), 
       'contain' => array(
             'Event' => array(
                   'conditions' => array(
                         'Event.date' => date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow)
                    )
             )
        )
  ));
```

Comment: _(FYI: I'm not the OP)_ If the goal is to return just the events (vs. your solution which returns an array of customers and their events), would you recommend just using the Hash class on this result set to remove the company or is there a solution like $this->Customer->Event->find('all',array('conditions'=>$c, 'contain'=>$contain))

Comment: It depends on what they're doing with the data.  It may not be necessary for them to separate out the Customer data, but yes, I'd most likely use the Hash class if you needed to.  If you tried doing the query by a normal `$this->Customer->Event->find()`, you will end up with all events on the date plus any Customers associated with those events that also have the appropriate company_id, rather than only those events that are both on the date and associated with Customers with the appropriate company_id, which is why I recommended to do the query "backwards."

Comment: That is what we needed, but the date condition for events is not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems that Events have many companies and companies have many events. This is ideal situation for hasAndBelongsToMany relationship. However, you have to focus on the className and joinTable properties to handle the non convenient naming of the join table customers.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

Comment: Are you sure an Event HasMany Company? An Event BelongsTo Customer. A Customer BelongsTo an Company which _I thought_ implies an Event BelongsTo a Company. Or am I missing some logic?

Comment: The methodology of database design obligatory make this condition. This is regardless what ever the asker's table design and what he has done. The story told us this.

Comment: There is no relation between events and company. That is what the question is all about. Events belong to customer that belongs to company. And what I want to do is to list events that are related to a particular company.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rethink the problem, because a user can be (customer or company) then they have a group or they are in a type of user. then a user belongs to a group or user type, this group can be a client or company .

users belongsto a group
group has many user

users hasmany events
events has many users

You can tell if is customer or company is the type of group that owns

table_*_*_group

id   ***_*___**    category    **__*_*_**    subcategory

1   ***_*___**     customer   **__*_*_**     example

2    ***_*___**    company     **__*_*_**    example